# Workaround to support org.junit.runners.Parameterized in Gradle

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, gradle

Gradle is unable to run JUnit tests annotated with:

```
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

@RunWith(value = Paremetrized.class)
public class UnitTest {
// ...
}
```

There is an [official issue](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3112) for this problem from June 2014 yet unsolved.

Are there any workarounds for enabling those tests (in Gradle 2.4)?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for JUnit's `Parameterized` is the open source third-party library [junit-dataprovider](https://github.com/TNG/junit-dataprovider). It is supported by Gradle (tested with 2.4).

The [usage](https://github.com/TNG/junit-dataprovider/wiki/Getting-started#usage) is similar:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.tngtech.java.junit.dataprovider.DataProvider;
import com.tngtech.java.junit.dataprovider.DataProviderRunner;
import com.tngtech.java.junit.dataprovider.UseDataProvider;

@RunWith(DataProviderRunner.class)
public class DataProviderTest {

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] dataProviderAdd() {
        // @formatter:off
        return new Object[][] {
                { 0, 0, 0 },
                { 1, 1, 2 },
                /* ... */
        };
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Test
    @UseDataProvider("dataProviderAdd")
    public void testAdd(int a, int b, int expected) {
        // Given:

        // When:
        int result = a + b;

        // Then:
        assertEquals(expected, result);
    }
}
```

The dependency line for Gradle:

```
testCompile 'com.tngtech.java:junit-dataprovider:1.9.3'
```